After removing the first principal component I reverse the PCA, but some of the data flip compared to original some not
In order to remove noise from a dataset (n variable, m measurements), I apply PCA on it, remove the first PC, and reconstruc the original data. This perfectly removes the noise from my data. However, some of the data series flip compared to the original data and what is expected while some other coincide to the expected trend.
Can someone explain why this happens? How can I fix this problem? or at least how can I predict which one of data series would flip without checking the data?
